# Read web feature service into R data.frame

Tags: r, xml

I have got this function to read Web Feature Service into R data.frame. I have used it for this **[url](https://hbmaps.hbrc.govt.nz/arcgis/services/emar/MonitoringSiteReferenceData/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typename=MonitoringSiteReferenceData&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:4326&Version=1.1.0)** and I managed to get the WFS as dataframe.

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)

readWFS_monitoringsites <- function(url){
  #Function to read a WFS and return a dataframe
  cat(url,"\n")

  # Dealing with https:
  if(substr(url,start = 1,stop = 5)=="http:"){
    getSites.xml <- xmlInternalTreeParse(url)
  } else {
    tf <- getURL(url, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)

    getSites.xml <- xmlParse(tf)
  }

  ds <- xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(getSites.xml, "//emar:MonitoringSiteReferenceData"))

  ds$Source <- url
  ds
}


df_sites <- readWFS_monitoringsites("https://hbmaps.hbrc.govt.nz/arcgis/services/emar/MonitoringSiteReferenceData/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typename=MonitoringSiteReferenceData&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:4326&Version=1.1.0")
```

When I changed the function for this **[url](https://hbmaps.hbrc.govt.nz/arcgis/services/WebMaps/RegulatoryIRIS/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typename=WebMaps_RegulatoryIRIS:All_Consents&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:4326&Version=1.1.0)**

```
readWFS_regulatoryIRIS <- function(url){
  #Function to read a WFS and return a dataframe
  cat(url,"\n")

  # Dealing with https:
  if(substr(url,start = 1,stop = 5)=="http:"){
    getSites.xml <- xmlInternalTreeParse(url)
  } else {
    tf <- getURL(url, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)

    getSites.xml <- xmlParse(tf)
  }

  ds <- xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(getSites.xml, "//emar:RegulatoryIRIS"))

  ds$Source <- url
  ds
}
df_iris <- readWFS_regulatoryIRIS("https://hbmaps.hbrc.govt.nz/arcgis/services/WebMaps/RegulatoryIRIS/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typename=WebMaps_RegulatoryIRIS:All_Consents&srsName=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.9:4326&Version=1.1.0")
```

I got this error

> Error in xpathApply.XMLInternalDocument(doc, path, fun, ...,
>   namespaces = namespaces,  :    error evaluating xpath expression
>   //emar:RegulatoryIRIS

I will highly appreciate any suggestions to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

The key part of the error message is the first line that you omitted :-)

```
 XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
```

Your XPath expression "//emar:RegulatoryIRIS" refers to a namespace *prefix* emar.
Either you define that in the call to getNodeSet() or it better be defined in the root/top-level node of the document.

In only one of the 4 documents I have retrieved from that specific URL today is xmlns:emar="http://www.lawa.org/nz/emar" defined in the root note.  However, even with that namespace prefix->URL map, there is no node named RegulatoryIRIS.

And in the other 3 documents, there are node names such as WebMaps_RegulatoryIRIS:All_Consents
which have the RegulatoryIRIS word in the namespace prefix, not the node name.

So either the URL is giving back content with different XML structure or your need to better understand the structure of the XML, or both.

But the error comes from emar not being a defined namespace prefix.
It is good to specify this in the call to getNodeSet() with, e.g.,

```
getNodeSet(doc, "//emar:RegulatoryIRIS", c(emar = "http://www.lawa.org.nz/emar"))
```

HTH